# How to change the http method in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to find a way to change the http method(POST/PUT) used when uploading to an s3 bucket with boto3 python's library, I haven't been able to find a way to do this, any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think POST is supported for s3 buckets?  My understanding is that the HTTP verbs are encapsulated by boto3 as `s3.Object().get()`, `s3.Object.put()`, etc., and according to the documentation (http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) post() is not implemented.

Comment: POST is [supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html), but there's not any reason I can see to use it outside of a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would need to register an [event](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/events.html). You can see an example where this is done in [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/handlers.py#L513). I am curious why you would want to do this though, as it would only make your life more difficult by forcing you to form encode the request as if it were submitted from an HTML form.

Copy for posterity:

```
def change_get_to_post(request, **kwargs):
# This is useful when we need to change a potentially large GET request
# into a POST with x-www-form-urlencoded encoding.
if request.method == 'GET' and '?' in request.url:
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.url, request.data = request.url.split('?', 1)
```

Comment: turns out, post is not implemented in boto3, so this is one way to do it, or just implementing the whole thing using requests. thanks.